# percentage of two int?

Tags: java, int, decimal

I want to get two ints, one divided by the other to get a decimal or percentage.
How can I get a percentage or decimal of these two ints?
(I'm not sure if it is right.. I'm probably way off...)
for example:

```
int correct = 25;
int questionNum = 100;
float percent = correct/questionNum *100;
```

This is how I thought I could do it, but it didn't work... I want to make the decimal (if there is one) into a percent out of 100 for example in this case it is %25. any ideas anyone?

Here is the correct code (thanks to Salvatore Previti!):

```
float correct = 25;
float questionNum = 100;
float percent = (correct * 100.0f) / questionNum;
```

(btw, I am making a project using this for a quiz checking program that is why I need the percentage or decimal)

Comment: Don't use float unless you aren't allowed to use double. You lose precision without much in the way of benefit.

Comment: percent should contain 25 in it.  Not sure what your exact issue is, seems unclear. Please update your question, and post the function where you are using this code.

Comment: @Eric ah silly me :) i've been doing too much C all day hehe Java and strict types.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am allowed to use double but how do i use it in this?

Comment: Everywhere you see `float`, substitute in `double`. Then do your math as `(double)n/v * 100;`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edited my code in my program but it gives me NaN as an answer, here is my code: (I changed the variables so it would be clear)
double percent =(double)correct/questionNum * 100;

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you don't add `.0f` it will be treated like it is an integer, and an integer division is a lot different from a floating point division indeed :)

```
float percent = (n * 100.0f) / v;
```

If you need an integer out of this you can of course cast the `float` or the `double` again in integer.

```
int percent = (int)((n * 100.0f) / v);
```

If you know your n value is less than 21474836 (that is (2 ^ 31 / 100)), you can do all using integer operations.

```
int percent = (n * 100) / v;
```

If you get NaN is because wathever you do you cannot divide for zero of course... it doesn't make sense.

Comment: 100F is sufficient. No need for the .0.

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti it gives me NAN as the answer when im using the float. with the int, it doesn't work at all..

Comment: If v is zero, this calculation doesn't make sense, and is the only way you can get NaN (a number divided zero is not a number).

Comment: v is equal to 4, let me check it again.

Comment: no, still not working and i checked it and v is equal to 4 and n is equal to 1

Comment: i changed n to a float and now i got the answer as infinity -_-

Comment: I got it!!!!!! i changed every variable into a float and now it is working!!! thanks!!

Answer (score 19):

Two options:

Do the division after the multiplication:

```
int n = 25;
int v = 100;
int percent = n * 100 / v;
```

Convert an `int` to a `float` before dividing

```
int n = 25;
int v = 100;
float percent = n * 100f / v;
//Or:
//  float percent = (float) n * 100 / v;
//  float percent = n * 100 / (float) v;
```

Comment: I get NAN as an answer.. any ideas?

Comment: @Baruch: Both `n` and `v` must be 0, if you're getting `NaN`

Comment: Please, be careful with integer overflow.
In case of overflow, you'll probably get negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

One of them has to be a float going in. One possible way of ensuring that is:

```
float percent = (float) n/v * 100;
```

Otherwise, you're doing [integer division, which truncates the numbers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.2). Also, you should be using `double` unless there's a good reason for the `float`.

The next issue you'll run into is that some of your percentages might look like 24.9999999999999% instead of 25%. This is due to precision loss in floating point representation. You'll have to decide how to deal with that, too. Options include a [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to "fix" the formatting or [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to represent exact values.

Comment: That's one of the many ways to do it. The important thing is that one of the numbers used in the division is a floating point number.

Comment: Yes ... you can do (n / (float)v) * 100;

Comment: No, the operation does not require any `float` values. See @Eric's answer.

Comment: @Loadmaster: That only works if `v` is evenly divisible by `n`. Otherwise you'll get rounding errors. The OP explicitly asked for a "decimal or percentage", and since this is for a quiz application, a non-fp answer won't work very well unless you want to set strict limits on the number of questions that can be on a quiz.

Answer (score 0):

```
float percent = (n / (v * 1.0f)) *100
```