# Can I perform simple division and multiplication on android

Tags: android

I wish to take the number retrieved and placed into count and find its percentage against the fullAttendance int. Here is my code:

```
attendanceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            attendanceRef.whereEqualTo("sessionID", "5I0PLcpgmwdcjKLYLgkU").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {


                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int fullAttendance = 12;
                        int count = 0;
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            count++;
                            attendanceNumbs = findViewById(R.id.attendanceNums);
                            attendanceNumbs.setText((count/fullAttendance)*100 + " %" + "\n Attendance for this session");
                        }
                        Log.d("TAG", count + "");
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Um,  yes.  * is multiplication and / is division

Comment: Possible duplicate of [percentage of two int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855387/percentage-of-two-int)

Comment: I am guessing that your problem is you need `(count/fullAttendance) * 100.0` here.  If you divide two ints, you'll get truncation, probably to zero, every time.  You need float/double division.

Comment: Yes Tim I keep getting 0 everytime. how could I change this to double?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `fullAttendance` and `count` variables are integer, so the result of their division will be integer too. You should declare one of the operands as `float` (double) or explicitly cast one of them on division, like this:

```
count/(float)fullAttendance
```

Comment: Perfect is there anyway to limit the numher or numbers after the decimal point @Nickolas M.

Comment: @SeanGallagher The easiest way of doing it is to get the result of the division as double (`count / (double) fullAttendance`) and then round it with the BigDecimal: `BigDecimal.valueOf(result).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble()`